# Unable to parse xml using spring batch in a spring boot project

Tags: xml, spring-batch

I'm trying to parse an XML file to JavaBean in a spring boot project by using spring batch and XStreamMarshaller. I spent a lot of time in writing class DateConverter to convert the right date for the XStreamMarshaller object. But it leads to me a dead end. I tried to replace Date as String, but the same exception showed again. Please help me to fix these codes.

This is the XML file:

```
<RECORDS>
    <RECORD>
        <emp_no>10001</emp_no>
        <birth_date>1953-09-02</birth_date>
        <first_name>Georgi</first_name>
        <last_name>Facello</last_name>
        <gender>M</gender>
        <hire_date>1986-06-26</hire_date>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <emp_no>10002</emp_no>
        <birth_date>1964-06-02</birth_date>
        <first_name>Bezalel</first_name>
        <last_name>Simmel</last_name>
        <gender>F</gender>
        <hire_date>1985-11-21</hire_date>
    </RECORD>
</RECORDS>
```

XmlFileDemoApp.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class XmlFileDemoApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(XmlFileDemoApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

XmlFileDemoJobConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
public class XmlFileDemoJobConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("xmlFileDemoWriter")
    private ItemWriter<? super NewEmployees> xmlFileDemoWriter;

    @Bean
    public Job xmlFileDemoJob() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("xmlFileDemoJob")
                .start(xmlFileDemoStep())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step xmlFileDemoStep() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("xmlFileDemoStep")
                .<NewEmployees, NewEmployees>chunk(1000)
                .reader(xmlFileDemoReader())
                .writer(xmlFileDemoWriter)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public StaxEventItemReader<NewEmployees> xmlFileDemoReader() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        StaxEventItemReader<NewEmployees> reader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("employees.xml"));
        reader.setFragmentRootElementName("RECORD");
        XStreamMarshaller unMarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
        ConverterMatcher[] converterMatchers = {new DateConverter()};
        unMarshaller.setConverters(converterMatchers);
        Map<String, Class> map = new HashMap<>(1);
        map.put("RECORD", NewEmployees.class);
        unMarshaller.setAliases(map);
        reader.setUnmarshaller(unMarshaller);
        return reader;
    }
}
```

XmlFileDemoWriter.java

```
@Component("xmlFileDemoWriter")
public class XmlFileDemoWriter implements ItemWriter<NewEmployees> {
    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends NewEmployees> list) throws Exception {
        for (NewEmployees employee : list) {
            System.out.println(employee);
        }
    }
}
```

DateConverter.java

```
public class DateConverter implements Converter {


    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class arg0) {
        return Date.class == arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public void marshal(Object arg0, HierarchicalStreamWriter arg1, MarshallingContext arg2) {
    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext arg1) {
        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
        try {
            calendar.setTime(dateFm.parse(reader.getValue()));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new ConversionException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return calendar.getTime();
    }
}
```

NewEmployees.java

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class NewEmployees {
    private int emp_no;
    private Date birth_date;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private String gender;
    private Date hire_date;
}
```

Apparently, yyyy-MM-dd is not correct. 
The error log is:

```
org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: XStream unmarshalling exception; nested exception is com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Cannot parse date
---- Debugging information ----
message             : Cannot parse date
date                : 1953-09-02
class               : java.util.Date
required-type       : java.util.Date
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.SingleValueConverterWrapper
wrapped-converter   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.basic.DateConverter
Default date pattern: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S z
Default era date pattern: yyyy-MM-dd G HH:mm:ss.S z
Alternative date pattern: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S z
Alternative date pattern[1]: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S a
Alternative date pattern[2]: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssz
Alternative date pattern[3]: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z
Alternative date pattern[4]: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SX
Alternative date pattern[5]: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX
Alternative date pattern[6]: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmX
Alternative date pattern[7]: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssa
path                : /RECORD/birth_date
line number         : 5
class[1]            : com.batch.testspringbatch.input.xmlFile.NewEmployees
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
version             : 1.4.10
```

---

Then I wrote a DateConverter to deal the time, then the error became:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.batch.testspringbatch.input.xmlFile.NewEmployees cannot be cast to com.batch.testspringbatch.input.xmlFile.NewEmployees
    at com.batch.testspringbatch.input.xmlFile.XmlFileDemoWriter.write(XmlFileDemoWriter.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ClassCastException in StaxEventItemReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57061393/classcastexception-in-staxeventitemreader)

Comment: Thank you, dude!!!!! It works!!!! You must be the angle!!!